# Pinnacle cart website directly showing html css code and not taking any affect

Tags: html, css, pinnacle-cart

I have a Pinnacle cart website. It was hacked and I recovered it but the problem I am facing that website directly showing html tag and css style code like below.

```
<b>Award Winning Products</b> | <b>Crown and Bridge</b> | <b>Dentures</b> | <b>Impression Materials</b> | <b>X-Ray Processing</b><br><i>One Minute at chairside</i> | <b>Anti-Fog System</b><br><i>Mirror Wipe</i> | <b>Saliva Ejector Holder</b>
```

or

```
<div style="font-size:18px;">Sore-Spotter</div>Locate sore spots in seconds
```

Website design are ok. Menu, products, content etc html tag and css style are showing directly and not taking any affect on the browser.
Why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could give us more code to work with, as  there is nothing necessarily wrong with the code you provided.

However, the problem is likely due to your file names in your header or something are lacking a proper `.html` or `.css` file extension, and the Apache server doesn't know any better than  to serve them as just text.

You can also try troubleshooting at https://validator.w3.org/ , copying and pasting your code to see if any  errors emerge.

Comment: I have checked that all files extension like .html exist their. Please check the live link: http://www.holmesdental.com

Answer (score 0):

I took another look at some of the code.

I noticed some sloppiness that needed to be cleaned up:

For instance:

`&lt;div style="font-size:18px;"&gt;QYK-FIX&lt;/div&gt;Process x-rays one minute at chair side`

needs to be changed to

`<div style="font-size:18px;">QYK-FIX</div>Process x-rays one  minute at chair side`

the and other strangeness is likely a product  of autogenerated  code.

FYI `&lt;` becomes an < when it is parsed by a webpage, and so that is where those are coming from. Was your html a result of copying and pasting?

The example I listed above was found inside of the tables you are using in the class `catalog-list`

I would say to open up your dev tools in browser, and search for where you are having these formatting issues and making sure that these weird code artifacts aren't persisting into your final product.